# How to format a variable in Ansible value

Tags: jinja2, ansible

Given that Ansible processes all variables through Jinja2, and doing something like this is possible:

```
- name: Debug sequence item value
  debug: msg={{ 'Item\:\ %s'|format(item) }}
  with_sequence: count=5 format="%02d"
```

Which correctly interpolates the string as:

```
ok: [server.name] => (item=01) => {"item": "01", "msg": "Item: 01"}
ok: [server.name] => (item=02) => {"item": "02", "msg": "Item: 02"}
ok: [server.name] => (item=03) => {"item": "03", "msg": "Item: 03"}
ok: [server.name] => (item=04) => {"item": "04", "msg": "Item: 04"}
ok: [server.name] => (item=05) => {"item": "05", "msg": "Item: 05"}
```

Why then doesn't this work:

```
- name: Debug sequence item value
  debug: msg={{ 'Item\:\ %02d'|format(int(item)) }}
  with_sequence: count=5
```

This apparently causes some sort of parsing issue which results in our desired string being rendered verbose:

```
ok: [server.name] => (item=01) => {"item": "01", "msg": "{{Item\\:\\ %02d|format(int(item))}}"}
```

Noting that in the above example `item` is a string because the default format of `with_sequence` is `%d`, and `format()` doesn't cast the value of `item` to the format required by the string interpolation `%02d`, hence the need to cast with `int()`.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It took me a couple of tries to get this right, but try this, instead:

```
debug: msg={{ 'Item\:\ %02d'|format(item|int) }}
```

Jinja2 is a bit funny.