# How do I pad an IP address' octets and turn it into a unique int id in an Ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Given an IP address like `127.0.0.1` (as a string), I want to drop the dots, pad each octet (ideally except for the first one) with zeros to a length of three digits and turn the result into an integer, e.g. `127000000001`. (Although I'm assuming that leading zeros would be dropped when converting from string to integer anyway.)

How do I go about doing that in Ansible?
I have the ip defined as `ip: "127.0.0.1"`
The octets can be obtained with `octets: "{{ ip.split('.')}}"`

I have found a [post that shows how to format strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18070010/2018047): `{{'%03d'|format(item|int) }}`

And I can join a list to a string using `result: modified_octets.join()`

What I'm struggling with is how to bring all that together. I know I can loop over the octets with an `with_items: octets`, and could thus apply the format to each `item`. But how would I join the result together into a list of items (i.e. `modified_octets`) again? (If I assign `item` to a variable using the `register` module, I'll only get the last octet's value; previous ones will be overridden by it...)

Update: It's not important whether I get a string or an int back, really, as long as the return value looks like an integer (i.e. no leading zeroes, no dots, numbers only, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't get `int` out of `{{ ... }}` expression because of how Ansible's templator works. You can test it with:

```
- name: 'this will print "int"'
  debug:
    msg: '{{ "1" | int | type_debug }}'
- name: 'this will print "1", but not 1'
  debug:
    msg: '{{ "1" | int }}'
```

If string id is still make sense to you, try this:

```
- set_fact:
    ip_id: "{% for i in my_ip.split('.') %}\
            {{ '%03d' | format(i|int) }}\
            {% endfor %}"
  vars:
    my_ip: 10.20.30.40
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You could define an empty string before starting your loop
2. Add (concatenate) the result of every octet to the string
3. Then casting the string to integer

   `String =""
   while loop
   modified_octet=-------
   String+=modified_octet   #string=string+modified_octet`

An other effective way 
for your example the output is integer number 
which is summation of the next numbers:

`12700000000001=12700000000000+00000000000001`

**For other example **
127.10.23.1 ==> 127010023001 which is summation of the next numbers
`0000000000001
0000000023000=23*10^3
0000100000000=10*10^6
1270000000000=10*10^9`

1. you can split the octets and casting (convert) them to integer
2. and multiple

`first octet from left in 10^9
   second                in 10^6
   3rd                   in 10^3
   Don't multiple  the last
   And sum the result`

3. then return the result 
   if you tell me which language you use I could write code
   Java or python

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `replace` filter to replace the dots with zeros.  The `int` filter will cast the string to an integer.

```
result: "{{ ip | replace('.', '00') | int }}"
```

Comment: Hmm.. and if ip is `111.111.111.111`?... and `int` will not give you integer when applied at the very end of template (see my answer).

Comment: That's a good point, guess my tests weren't good enough.  Looks like there's hope for this feature in 2.5 - https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/32738.

Comment: I like the creative use of `replace()`, but sadly, as Konstantin pointed out, this solution won't do... :(