# Convert single to double digits by appending zero in Ansible

Tags: python, string, ansible

I have the below playbook:

```
   - name: Add hosts
     include_tasks: "{{ playbook_dir }}/gethosts1.yml"
     vars:
       PROFILE_NUM: "{{ my_result }}"
     loop: "{{ query('sequence', 'start=1 end='+(PROFILES)) }}"
     loop_control:
       loop_var: my_result
```

I run the playbook as:

```
ansible-playbook test.yml -e  PROFILES=12
```

This gets me PROFILE_NUM as 1,2,3,4,5...12

However, i want PROFILE_NUM to be two digits i.e 01,02,03,04,05....12

I tried the following but it errors out `PROFILE_NUM: "%02d{{ my_result }}"`

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close, you're looking for:

```
PROFILE_NUM: '{{ "%02d" | format(my_result) }}'
```

which will use jinja2 to format the string "%02d" using the parameters `my_result`, giving you:

```
01
```

if you pass a 1.

Answer (score 1):

You may check this related post:
 [Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)

(if using python3) consider to take the second approach:

```
print("{:02d}".format(1))
```

Or the one below using f-strings.

Comment: Could you please suggest @Alexander Brockmeier an ansible code where I'm assigning it to a variable `PROFILE_NUM: "{{ my_result }}"`

Comment: @Ashar
I apologize for only using ansible a few times, yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050911/how-to-format-a-variable-in-ansible-value 
may help you.